# How to display file contents from SharePoint document library?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, file

I'm doing a REST request to get file contents from a file in my SharePoint library. So far, I've managed to get the actual contents from any file I need, and I've tried converting to binary. But, for example, if I try to pull information from a Word document, it comes out something like this:

```
üÜé×·Äxj¨ADtÙ$Kq"´¹æ7!v9gaL·;p¯ÀÄÄ .B"Sí¯þ´è|Û 3ÐÑÑ _Xä k
```

It works fine on .txt files, but I'm trying to do it from a .onepkg, so what can I do to convert this data into readable content?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure if this will help you but Here is a sample of code that I use to pull a pdf file into the browsers memory so I can then use another rest request to upload the file to Adobe Echosign.

If you know the file's url or if you have done a Get on the library via the document ID I would use the FieldValuesAsText.FileRef for the server relative url to the file.

My page has a config object that stores everything so when you see config.blob = this.response that's just how I'm storing the data.

```
    function GetFileContents(){
    var RequestURL = "YourFileURLHERE"
    console.log(RequestURL);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status ==200){
            console.log(this.response, typeof this.response);
            //Your variable where you want to hold the data
            config.blob = this.response;
        }    
    }
    xhr.open('GET', RequestURL, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
};
```